# How to add attribute for HAML block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I would like to add class attribute for HAML `= link_to "#" do` block?

```
= link_to "#" {class: "class-name"} do
  image_tag "image_path.ext"
  Link Sample Text
```

The code above does not work.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer if that resolved your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a comma between the target link and the `options` hash. Try this

```
= link_to '#', { class: 'btn btn-primary' } do
  = image_tag 'image_url'
```